# Weird error in R

Tags: r

For some reason, the if-statement in my code generates some weird error in R whenever I run my function:

```
Error in if (P > 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

My function is supposed to return the smallest eigenvalue of the symmetric, positive semi-definite matrix A, if B is the identity matrix. I tested my function using

```
set.seed(12345)
a <- crossprod(matrix (rnorm(40), 10 ,4)) / 10
b <- diag(1, 4, 4)
```

and it does yield the correct answer (I checked using the eigen function.)

Anyway, I need to set theta to the value that minimizes a certain function. For the example I used, that value is (-Q - sqrt(under.sqrt)) / (2 * P), but in general it depends on the sign of P. Why does my if-statement give me such an error? I have been stuck here for a while. Any help would be appreciated.

```
myFunction <- function(A, B, eps = 1e-6, itmax = 100, verbose = FALSE) {

  n <- nrow(A)
  m <- ncol(A)
  x <- rep (1, n)
  u <- A %*% x
  v <- B %*% x
  r <- t(u) %*% x
  s <- t(v) %*% x
  y <- r / s

  itel <- 1

  repeat {
    tmax <- 0

    for(j in 1:m) {
      P <- (u[j] * B[j, j]) - (v[j] * A[j, j])
      Q <- (r * B[j, j]) - (s * A[j, j])
      R <- (r * v[j]) - (s * u[j])

      under.sqrt <- Q^2 - 4 * P * R

      # Error right here
      if (P > 0) {
        theta <- (-Q + sqrt(under.sqrt)) / (2 * P)
      }

      else {
        theta <- (-Q - sqrt(under.sqrt)) / (2 * P)
      }


      x[j] <- x[j] + theta
      r <- r + 2 * theta * u[j] + A[j, j] * theta * theta
      s <- s + 2 * theta * v[j] + B[j, j] * theta * theta
      u <- u + theta * A[ ,j]
      v <- v + theta * B[, j]

      y <- r / s

      tmax <- max(tmax, abs(theta))
    }

      if ((tmax < eps) || (itel == itmax)) {
        break()
      }

      itel <- itel + 1  

  }

  return(y)
}
```

Comment: What are the values of A and B you are calling with? It looks like your code will only work if these are square matrices

Comment: I used this:

`set.seed(12345)`

`a <- crossprod(matrix (rnorm(40), 10 ,4)) / 10`

`b <- diag(1, 4, 4)`

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I will try to figure something out when it isn't 3:30 in the morning...

Comment: `x` is blowing up and causing `P` to become `NaN`

Answer (score 4):

You algorithm is not stable. Using `options(error=recover)` you can browse the function where it is going wrong:

```
Browse[1]> P
[1] NaN
Browse[1]> theta
     [,1]
[1,]  Inf
```

Here you can see that `P` is `NaN` and this is caused by `theta` blowing up to infinite values. This feeds through to `x`, `u`, `v` and ultimately `P` and makes the comparison fail.

Comment: Now that I've gone back to thoroughly check my work, I don't even think that if-statement was needed. Remind me never to code at 3 in the morning...

Comment: But thanks for all your responses. I will keep your tips in mind to check future errors!

Answer (score 2):

Here's my bet: P is NA

```
> if(NA > 0){}
Error in if (NA > 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

**P renders NaN:**

```
> if(NaN > 0){}
Error in if (NaN > 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

regarding the guess that P is a vector:

```
> if(1:2 > 0){}
NULL
Warning message:
In if (1:2 > 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Comment: I think you are right. P seems to be getting super large and ultimately becomes NA. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `P` is a single value? Ie, not a vector of length > 1?

Comment: I added a print(P) in the middle of my code, and it does yield a single value. I don't understand why it won't work in my if-statement, though.

Comment: Then perhaps as indeed @Raffael suggests, it could be a NA

Answer (score 0):

Try `ifelse`:

```
theta <- ifelse(P > 0,
                (-Q + sqrt(under.sqrt)) / (2 * P),
                (-Q - sqrt(under.sqrt)) / (2 * P))
```

`ifelse` can handle NA comparison:

```
ifelse(NA>0,print("x"),print("y"))
[1] NA

if(NA>0) print("x") else print("y")
Error in if (NA > 0) print("x") else print("y") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Comment: This looks like a joke ... could you tell us why somebody would do that?

Comment: Could you tell us why not?

Comment: because you are vectorizing the condition while it is clear that a single value is to be handled

Comment: so you suggest coding with error-tolerance ... I hope you're not programming for nuclear power plants

Comment: Oh, I can assure you that is not the case!